# Why is my render not showing quick fire/smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I'm trying to render my fire/smoke but it seems that it renders a gray smoke domain instead of my fire/smoke.
Any idea?
I used the quick smoke effect.

[image]

**Update:** here is my file:
[image]

Comment: Just a thought, have you fiddled with the domain material, and accidentally given it a surface shader? That wouldn't show in solid mode, as the domain's maximum draw visibility gets set to wire by quick smoke, but it would still show up in rendered mode and in full renders.

Comment: uploaded my file.

Comment: @MrZak If you enable _Smoke Adaptive Domain_, which it looks like the OP has done, only the part that has any smoke or fire and a small margin will be rendered. I just tested this.

Comment: @juFo Did you by any chance run Quick Smoke while you had Blender Render active, and switch to Cycles afterwards?

Comment: The domain does have a BI material, so I believe my previous comment is the key to what happened here. The proper way to fix it, would be to create a material, but considering you haven't done much work yet, the simplest and quickest way is probably to start over, and remember to change the render engine before you run _Quick Smoke_.

Comment: Before creating particles switch to cycles render
so you can see particles in cycles render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Smoke domain material node setup is empty. Nodes are required for a smoke domain using cycles.
See an example here (smoke only):

[image]

A more complex setup for fire+smoke:

[image]

Comment: Please add images inline, not as links.

Comment: Thanks it works. How to make the smoke more black? It's almost not visible